# tkinter behaves unexpectedly when binding to double_click event - what is a double click?

Tags: python-3.x, events, tkinter, double-click

I'm using tk 8.6 with python 3.5.

I'm writing an application where I need to act on both single and double clicks, and sometimes double clicks can occur very close together.

The tk documentation states that when you bind to both single and double click events, the first click generates a Button-1 event, and the second a Double-Button-1 event. And this is what I observe when I double click once.

When I repeat the double click, I would expect to see the following events - single, double, single, double. This is what I see when I leave a significant pause between the two double clicks. When I repeat one quickly after the other, I see single, double, double, double. As I slow the operation down, the threshold for seeing one or the other is roughly the inter-click delay for discriminating a double click from two singles.

It appears that tkinter treats any click following quickly on from another as a double click. I would have expected it to qualify the first click with whether it was the second click of a double, and if it was, to treat the 'third' click as a single click. This behaviour means that the sequence of events generated by a pair of double clicks varies depending on the inter-double delay.

My workaround to get consistent behaviour has been to stop binding to double, time the singles, and do my own delay thresholding for double clicks. This I figured was cleaner than trying to interpret whether doubles were 'really' double clicks.

Is this behaviour a bug in tkinter?

What do other GUI managers do under these circumstances?

Is there a definition of what should happen under these circumstances?

/edit/ I've just had it brought to my attention that triple and quadruple clicks are also supported by tk. However, I still think there's something unexpected in tk's behaviour. If I bind to only single click, then my 'two double clicks', basically a quadruple click, generates four single events. Therefore I would expect on binding to single and double only, it should interpret a quadruple in terms of single and double clicks only as single, double, single, double. I guess my eventual program documentation should mention that I don't use triple or quad clicks. But hey, I've got my workaround. //edit/

/edit2/ I've bound to triple and quadruple clicks to see what happens, and it gets more buggy. I never get a quad event with a quad click. I do get a sequence of single, double, triple, double events delivered. I've also had a single, double, triple, triple, with AFAICS the same input timing. I'll stick to binding to singles only, and doing my own timing! //edit2/

Comment: I think this isn't an unexpected event, Triple click will generate `double click` event twice.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA So it sounds like my expectation is wrong. On what system does triple click generate two doubles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the [docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm#M11):

> The Double, Triple and Quadruple modifiers are a convenience for specifying double mouse clicks and other repeated events. They cause a particular event pattern to be repeated 2, 3 or 4 times, and also place a time and space requirement on the sequence: for a sequence of events to match a Double, Triple or Quadruple **pattern**, all of the events must
> occur close together in time and without substantial mouse motion in between. For example, `<Double-Button-1>` is equivalent to `<Button-1><Button-1>` with the extra time and space requirement.

-> Section *[Multiple matches](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm#M55)*

> If more than one binding matches a particular event and they have the same tag, then the most specific binding is chosen and its script is evaluated. The following tests are applied, in order, to determine which of several matching sequences is more specific:

> (c) if the modifiers specified in one **pattern** are a subset of the modifiers in another pattern, then the pattern with more modifiers is more specific.

So this should work:

```
def func2(event):
    print('double')
    widget.unbind('<Double-1>')

def func1(event):
    print('single')
    widget.bind('<Double-1>', func2)

widget.bind('<Button-1>', func1)
```

**Edit**

and it works, try:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

up = tk.Frame(root)
up.grid(column=0, row=0,columnspan=3,sticky='n')
s1 = tk.Label(up, text='spacer')
s1.pack(fill='both',expand=1)

def func4(event):
    print('Quadruple')
    s1.unbind('<Quadruple-1>')

def func3(event):
    print('triple')
    s1.unbind('<Triple-1>')
    s1.bind('<Quadruple-1>', func4)

def func2(event):
    print('double')
    s1.unbind('<Double-1>')
    s1.bind('<Triple-1>', func3)
    

def func1(event):
    print('single')
    s1.bind('<Double-1>', func2)

s1.bind('<Button-1>', func1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, thanks Atlas, I've read the docs. Check out my edits to the OP.

Comment: Ummm, i edited your answer using python :p , so please check if i actually formatted or made some mistakes to your texts, please

Comment: The idea that I had, except now you need to have triple or quattro, is to bind the double-1 in the single and unbind it after the function is done to make sure the single one is the most specific event to call. However, would be nice to know.

Comment: @Cool Cloud seems perfect thanks. Don't know how to mark code on my phone :D

Comment: @Atlas435 Thanks. Now I've got over the horror of dynamic binding and unbinding, it does represent logically and cleanly what I want to do. The triple works now, but it still doesn't respond with a quadruple, only a single, double, triple, single. Fortunately I don't need 3 and 4, only quickly repeated doubles. Not sure what the Frame, expand, sticky are meant to achieve, it still results in a tiny window where the close isn't visible, but perhaps that's a function of my linux Mint 18 perhaps? The width and height spec as seen in my answer give a sensible looking window.

Comment: @Atlas435 the code marking is just backticks(`) for one liners and triple backticks for multiple lines, right?

Comment: I just looked in the edit section of this posting, it's true. Suddenly I couldn't see it on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Following the lead of Atlas435, I've now got another way to implement my 'two double clicks' as asked for in the question. My workaround involved binding to only single events and manually timing them, which was a bit impure as it duplicated the double-click timing settings set via the OS. A distributed case of DRY.

I'm not sure if dynamically binding and unbinding was really what I was after, but it is straightforward, and it does work. It's a good expression of exactly what I want, which is 'don't respond double click when the previous click was the second one of a double'.

```
import tkinter as tki

root = tki.Tk()

s1 = tki.Label(root, text='click here', width=15, height=3)
s1.pack()

def func2(event):
    print('double')
    s1.unbind('<Double-1>')   

def func1(event):
    print('single')
    s1.bind('<Double-1>', func2)

s1.bind('<Button-1>', func1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you kindly accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Comment: @Atlas435 Patience, I'm still typing. I was just adding this answer as it addressed my specific question, and didn't complicate things with triple or quad clicks. Your demo works, but I've yet to test it in my application.

Comment: Sorry, it's kind of reflexive while I don't understand why people won't appreciate the invested time. PS: good idea to make a minimal example.

Comment: What should this code do? `return self.func(*args)`

Comment: Doh! Working in the application now, wrong call signature to unbind().

Comment: I really cant help if I don't see code. Please make a question about it.